# SmartClient object always have extra data

Tags: smartclient

I am storing advanced criteria to my database.
But get criteria always fetch smartClient data as well. Is there any way to exclude those information while saving to database and atach it from browser onloading data from database. It just extra load to server in sending request and receiving response.

Please find attached image, I marked it with blue.[image: ImageWithSmartClientData]

Answer (score 0):

ListGrid.getCriteria doesn't retrieve extra information. Try to evaluate

> isc.JSON.encode(grid.getCriteria())

I get something like:

```
"{
    "_constructor":"AdvancedCriteria", 
    "operator":"and", 
    "criteria":[
        {
            "fieldName":"isCanvasAPI", 
            "operator":"notEqual", 
            "value":true, 
            "_constructor":"AdvancedCriteria"
        }
    ]
}"
```